# Python Error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python

can i know why im getting this error?
Error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

```
File "D:\bi\pinjaman.py", line 64, in <module>
    prediksi = load_model.predict(df)
```

Code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/12O3JS1xOLgQnYHZ3w_5ko56QpUN5bkM6/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred by NaN value is exist in your data or exceed range of data type.

Add this code in pinjaman.py's 63 row.
You can see how many NaN values in your data.

```
print(df.isnull().sum())
```

[image]

This is result of that code.
'Penghasilan' and 'Jumlah' column has NaN value.

Comment: Can i know how to remove value "Penghasilan" and "Jumlah" with NaN values?

Comment: You can remove or fill NaN values. Use df.fillna() method or df.dropna() method.